# Screenshot of remote computer

Tags: java

Hello I was doing a program of taking a snapshot of remote computer.

I have done up to.

**ScreenServer.java.**

```
import java.net.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class ScreenServer {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        BufferedImage screen;

        while (true) {
            ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(6659);
            Socket client = server.accept();

            Rectangle size = new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
            screen = robot.createScreenCapture(size);
            int[] rgbData = new int[(int) (size.getWidth()*size.getHeight())];
            screen.getRGB(0,0, (int) size.getWidth(), (int) size.getHeight(), rgbData, 0, (int) size.getWidth());

            OutputStream baseOut = client.getOutputStream();
            ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(baseOut);

            ImageIO.write(screen, "png", new File("d:\\orig_screen.png"));
            out.writeObject(size);

            for (int x = 0; x < rgbData.length; x++) {
                out.writeInt(rgbData[x]);
            }

            out.flush();
            server.close();
            client.close();
            out.close();
            baseOut.close();
        }
    }
}
```

**ScreenClient.java**

```
import java.net.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class ScreenClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Socket server = new Socket("172.22.6.50",6659);

        ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(server.getInputStream());

        Rectangle size = (Rectangle) in.readObject();

        int[] rgbData = new int[(int)(size.getWidth() * size.getHeight())];

        for (int x = 0; x < rgbData.length;x++) {
            rgbData[x] = in.readInt();
        }

        in.close();
        server.close();

        BufferedImage screen = new BufferedImage((int) size.getWidth(), (int) size.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

        screen.setRGB(0,0, (int) size.getWidth(), (int) size.getHeight(), rgbData, 0,(int)size.getWidth());

        ImageIO.write(screen, "png", new File("d:\\screen.png"));
    }
}
```

But it's not working properly.  The server takes it's own snapshot.  Please provide a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The server takes it's own snapshot...

Well, obviously it can't take a snapshot of the screen of some other random computer.  It would be a *massive* security hole if it could do *that*!!

If you want to take a snapshot of a computer's screen, you have to do it from a program executing on that computer, or via some remote desktop protocol.  In other words, the computer has to be set up / configured to allow this to happen.

---

I think your problem is that you are simply misunderstanding the way those two programs are **intended** to be used.  You are supposed to run the `ScreenServer` app on the machine whose screen you want to snapshot and the `ScreenClient` app on the machine where you want to view the snapshot.

You should also be aware that if you run the `ScreenServer` app on a machine, **any other computer on the network** can capture its screen.  This is very insecure.

Comment: No the screenclient.java is running on client system

Comment: @vijesh - but `ScreenClient.java` doesn't contain the code to make the screen capture.  That code is in `ScreenServer.java`.  See the line that says `robot.createScreenCapture(size);`?

Comment: oh!.Can u provide the code to sent the picture (snapshot)from client to server.and server code for receving the same.

Comment: @vijesh - this is a programming questions site.  The idea is that you write the code, and we answer your questions to help you do that.

Answer (score 2):

You are capturing the server's screen shot. see [here](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue182.html) for help.